# Schematic view of (co)homology.

Tags: differential-topology, homology-cohomology

Are there any resources where I can get more pictorial intuition about the Homology and Cohomology classes? I mean is there anything that clarifies the homology classes of some simple shapes and proceed to differential cohomology of those simple shapes so I can get some shematic idea about them ?

Answer (score 1):

The introductions to chapters 2 and 3 in Hatcher's "Algebraic topology" are what is best to start with. nice pictures and good intuition.